# I want to prepare meaningful charts and polarization chart with the data I have

Tags: python, visualization, excel

I am a bachelor student that is preparing a project for my network science course. I have some data that I got via questionnaire. This data shows people that they prefer studying online or in presence, their age, and gender. I want to prepare network charts and a polarization chart but I am not very experienced with these so I am not sure about what kind of chart I can prepare with the data I have. I am familiar with python so I can create them via it or some other tools. An example from my data;

```
id,preference,gender,age
1,9,1,26
2,2,2,22
3,0,2,24
4,9,2,24
5,10,2,21
6,9,2,20
7,5,2,24
8,5,1,23
9,8,2,26
10,8,1,26
```

Preferences goes from 0 to 10. It is the level of prefrences. 0 means online, 5 means notr, 10 means in presence and between them are the power level of their preference like 8 means the person gives 5 point to in presence while he/she gives 2 point to online. 10 means person gives 5 point to in presence and 0 to online. I hope I am clear here. The most imporant thing I want to build is the polarization chart that shows their preference but I have no idea about how to do it. Here is an example of polarization chart;

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note that polarization chart is not some standard chart that exists out there. It is used in the image you cited because they were comparing how polarized users in that sample were. Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to plot in your example, of online vs offline preference?

Comment: @hssay thank you for your answer. Sorry for my late reply, I got covid and trying to deal with it. it is told to me that I need to prepare a polarization like in this picture for the online vs offline preference. I have their preference and there are some neutral people who like to give an equal number to both. I need to show them like in the image but I could not figure out how to prepare a polarization chat.